# How do you decode struct numbers for testing in anchor?

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, borsh

I have the following

```
pub fn initialize_state(
    ctx: Context<InitializeState>,
    deposit_cap: u64,
) -> Result<()> {
    let mut state_account = ctx.accounts.state_account.load_init()?;
    state_account.deposit_cap = deposit_cap;
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(deposit_cap: u64)]
pub struct InitializeState<'info> {
    ....
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct State {
    ....,
    pub deposit_cap: u64
}
```

When I test in js i do the following.

```
let depositCap = new BN(1_000_000)
const txInitState = await program.methods.initializeState(
      depositCap
    ).accounts({....})....

let state = await program.account.state.fetch(stateAccount)
console.log(state)

{....,
depositCap: <BN: 4000000000000000>
}
```

How do I compare the input of depositCap=1_000_000 with this struct depositCap for testing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
state.depositCap.eq(depositCap)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assert on both to check if they are equal or not.

```
assert.equal(depositCap.toNumber(), state.depositCap.toNumber());
```

Comment: no this doesnt work, i believe because the encoding of *depositCap: <BN: 4000000000000000>* is big endian byte array (i think). so to number is on the array.  Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits